# How can I figure out how much a div shifts when a translate:scale is applied?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that I need to scale along with all the children. I'm using CSS transform:scale() to do this. I also need a background that fills the container behind it to scale alongside it, which i'm doing manually (If I keep it in the same div that is being scaled, the background won't take up the full page).

Scaling the size is easy enough, but when I scale the div it seems to also shift things. I have a div aligned with the background. When both get scaled, the div is no longer aligned with the background the same way. You can see what I mean here:

https://jsfiddle.net/fkg2v5w0/

```js
var scale = .5;

var container = document.querySelector(".container2");
var toTransform = document.querySelector(".toTransform2");


toTransform.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
container.style.backgroundImage = `radial-gradient(black ${4*scale}px, white ${4*scale}px)`;
container.style.backgroundSize = `${100*scale}px ${100*scale}px`;
container.style.backgroundPosition = `${0}px ${0}px`;
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: radial-gradient(black 4px, white 4px);
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-position:0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  top: 0px 
}
.container2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left:595px;
  top: 0px 
}
.toTransform, .toTransform2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.child, .child2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 250px;
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="toTransform">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="toTransform2">
    <div class="child2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to change the backgroundPosition property, but I have no idea how to figure out how much needs to be applied. There must be some math to it, but i've been unable to figure it out. Does anyone know how Scale ends up translating everything?

Comment: `transform:scale()` doesn't **move** elements at all.

Comment: Can you explain what i'm seeing in my code sample then? The background gets scaled the same amount as scale(), but the red square is no longer aligned with the dots.

Comment: I have no idea what your JS is doing. Perhaps a **simpler** example?

Comment: This was as simple as I could think of. All the JS is doing is taking the background CSS in container, scaling it down, and applying it to container2

Comment: Go look up the `transform-origin` property.

Comment: `transform:scale(2)` will make the element **4** times larger. 2x * 2y = 4xy - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/gwQxwo

Comment: `.toTransform, .toTransform2 {  transform-origin: top left; }` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look up the `transform-origin` property.

References [**here**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/transform-origin/) and **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)**.

> The transform-origin property is used to change the position of the
>   origin of transformation of an element.

Change:

```
.toTransform, .toTransform2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

To:

```
.toTransform, .toTransform2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: top left; /* Add this */
}
```

---

```js
var scale = .5;

var container = document.querySelector(".container2");
var toTransform = document.querySelector(".toTransform2");


toTransform.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
container.style.backgroundImage = `radial-gradient(black ${4*scale}px, white ${4*scale}px)`;
container.style.backgroundSize = `${100*scale}px ${100*scale}px`;
container.style.backgroundPosition = `${0}px ${0}px`;
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: radial-gradient(black 4px, white 4px);
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px
}
.container2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 595px;
  top: 0px
}
.toTransform,
.toTransform2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: top left;
}
.child,
.child2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 250px;
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="toTransform">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="toTransform2">
    <div class="child2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Perhaps you can understand what's going on in this simple example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
section {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
section::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: darkorchid;
}
.el {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: coral;
  position: relative;
}
.el:not(:first-child) {
  transform: scale(2);
}
.el--two {
  transform-origin: center center;
  /* default, same as 50% 50% */
}
.el--three {
  transform-origin: top left;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="el el--one"></div>
  <div class="el el--two"></div>
  <div class="el el--three"></div>
</section>
```